# How do I get the MIME type of a file basing on its content and not its extension?

Tags: files

I want to get the exact MIME type basing on the file content, not its extension.
I have used PHP methods and the API exposed by a module, but they return the MIME type basing on the file extension.

How do I get the MIME type from the file content?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have the file binary source sent in a post request **JSON** encoded or any encoding method you could get the MIME type like in the following piece of code

```
$data = base64_decode(trim($_REQUEST['file']));
$finfo = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($finfo, $data, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
finfo_close($finfo);
// get file type png. jpg
$ext = $mime_type ? str_replace('image/', '', $mime_type) : 'png';
```

**Hint**:Its better to send the file mime type in the request as encoding and decoding may cause not get the MIME type.

Using **file_get_contents**

```
$buffer = file_get_contents($url);
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$ext = $finfo->buffer($buffer);
```

More information found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php)

**Save** the file using [file_save_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7) to be a managed file and you could then use it as a field in any entity

Comment: thanks for your response but I have already tried this it's not working,

Comment: do you get  a post request or have the file url get it via file get contents

Comment: No, i don't have any post request, i want to get mime type in drupal hook_file_validate where i have file object.    https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_validate/7

Comment: @MohammedGomma +1 for the `file_get_contents()` example!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get the MIME type of a file using [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function.

```
$mime_type = mime_content_type($path_to_the_file);
```

I've just tested it on my local machine; placed a `test.pdf` file in my home folder and renamed it giving it no and an incorrect extension. In both cases I got the right MIME type:

> ```
> $ ls
> test.pdf
>
> $ drush eval 'var_dump(mime_content_type("/home/elin/test.pdf"))'
> string(15) "application/pdf"
>
> $ mv test.pdf test
> $ drush eval 'var_dump(mime_content_type("/home/elin/test"))'
> string(15) "application/pdf"
>
> $ mv test test.jpg
> $ drush eval 'var_dump(mime_content_type("/home/elin/test.jpg"))'
> string(15) "application/pdf"
>
> $ mv test.jpg test.png
> $ drush eval 'var_dump(mime_content_type("/home/elin/test.png"))'
> string(15) "application/pdf"
> ```

Comment: Please change your file extention pdf to png then Check what type of mime you get

Comment: @KamalOberoi The same result. Updated my answer with the output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have used it and not able to get correct mime type.. i have always got application/octect-stream.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? I've tested it on PHP 5.5.9